# Talend : modifying Webservice call timeout on a job

Tags: web-services, talend, karaf

I have a job, using a `tESBConsumer` component to call a distant webservice.
This webservice takes between 55-65s to answer : default timeout is set to 60s : I have sometimes read Timeout on this webservice call, I want to push it a bit.

I am deploying the job on a jobserver (not on karaf, as we have split configuration : karaf is for services only, jobserver for the jobs).

Thus, talend advice on configuring timeout is to use the `org.apache.cxf.http.conduits-common.cfg` file, which is a file only available on a Karaf, not on a jobserver ! [(See talend doc)](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=272769614)

=> Is there a way to configure read timeout option on a jobserver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, using the advanced settings of tESBConsumer works in this case, even if it says that it is only working on the studio.
So the "timeout" fields could be used for a deployment on a jobserver.